# how to create order in magento 2 with rest api

Tags: rest, api, magento, integration, magento2

i had check the all the answer for create the order in magneto 2 using rest api. but there is one problem that i have to make the 6-7 call for create the order.
like

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136028/magento-2-create-order-using-rest-api/156446#156446

Finally after that process i can create order.there is any another way to create order with the only one call and that process become short and easy.